# Prevent Users from installing Windows Updates on Terminal Server

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016, windows-update, rds, terminal-server

I'm trying to manage a RDS environment running Windows Server 2016. It's been noticed that Users logged into the terminal server receive prompts for and are able to install Windows Updates. The customer has requested this feature be limited to admins only.

According to Microsoft's documentation this is expected default behavior. The following articles recommend using the Group Policy `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Remove access to use all Windows Update features.`:

[How to block user access to Windows Update on Windows Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/block-user-access-windows-update)

[Use Group Policy to configure Windows Update for Business](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-wufb-group-policy#i-want-to-manage-the-update-settings-a-user-can-access)

However, applying this policy (at least on Server 2016) blocks *everyone* from installing Updates, **including admins**.

[Here is a question from someone having the same issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/949001/disable-access-to-windows-update-for-users-on-2016-rds-server) which includes no apparent solution, not even the ability to prevent users from merely receiving update notifications.

[This is a question about someone struggling to temporarily disable the policy](https://serverfault.com/questions/953797/turning-off-the-remove-access-to-use-all-windows-update-features-group-policy) in order to be able to install updates. While an ugly workaround at best, I seem to be able to force Windows Update to actually *read* the current policy by running `usoclient StartScan`. I suppose this method could be turned into a powershell-script, however the update-scan can take forever sometimes, so this isn't really practical for manually triggering an update in a timely manner. Not to mention the fact that, according to the question, this *only* works because the server is still running v1607.

Is it possible to install an Update using `usoclient` even though the policy removing access to Windows Update features is active? I haven't tested this, as installing the Update would prevent me from performing further testing until another Update is available.

Is there a way to apply the aforementioned policy to Users only?

I'd honestly even be happy with a way to prevent update notifications from being shown to users. It's not strictly necessary that they're unable to install updates whatsoever, as it seems unlikely to me that anyone will feel like opening the Windows Update settings menu unpromted.

Comment: Computer configurations apply computer-wide, for all accounts on the computer. What about using a central patch management server for your patching? I would guess that is what MS intends for you to do in this case.